# MonoDevelop C# - build Errors

Tags: c#, monodevelop

I get the following Errors(not warnings) when i build:

[image]

I'm pretty sure i'm either missing a plugin or did not import something. How do i fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do these Mono/xbuild warnings mean and how do I fix them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228499/what-do-these-mono-xbuild-warnings-mean-and-how-do-i-fix-them)

Comment: @Nasreddine these aren't warnings. these are errors. they are two different things

Comment: Try compiling for .NET 4.0

Comment: @FilipBulovic i do not know what that means

Comment: @JayC the errors are the result of that first warning.

Comment: which one do i use: .NET 4.0 or .NET 4.0 Client Profile? And what's the difference?

Comment: Do not know what is project about so can not really tell, try both I would say.

Comment: Do not use client profile; that is a limited .NET for use by browsers, Silverlight, and such. Client profile is not supported by Mono; trying to use it is causing your problems.

Comment: also how do i add arguments when i compile in monodevelop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From left pane in default view right click on project to invoke context menu. Select Options. On Project Options dialog under Build->General at the top of property page is Target framework, combo box, where different version of .NET framework can be selected.
To add Run parameters select Run->General property page, in the same dialog. The second field is Parameters. You enter them space separated as on command line.

Comment: also how do i add arguments when i compile in monodevelop?